# Is it possible to store a cookie to browser from servlet

Tags: javascript, jsp, cookies, browser, setcookie

Can i store a cookie returned by a REST call to the clients browser. The rest call is made from a jsp page. Ideas or solutions will be helpful.
What i need is from abc.com i am calling a webservice of xyz.com which requires authentication. On sucessful authentication xyz.com is returning a cookie and i want to store it in the browser so that if open xyz.com in another tab it should not ask for authentication.

Thanks,

Rahul

Comment: What happened when you tried it? Didn't it work? Where is your code to make the rest and where is your code to send the cookie?

Comment: Hi Quentin, Thanks for the reply. I wanted to know is this possible. I didnt got any ideas of doing it. What i need is from abc.com i am calling a webservice of xyz.com which requires authentication. On sucessful authentication xyz.com is returning a cookie and i want to store it in the browser so that if open xyz browser in a tab i should not ask for authentication. A kind of SSO is what i am trying to implement.

Answer (score 0):

You can set browser cookie from java servlets - i will suggest make authentication server side, get content and set cookie. (for more detail u can look java doc or tutorial of http response/request)

```
HttpServletResponse.addHeader("Set-Cookie", "cookie string");
```

OR

```
Cookie cookie = new Cookie("name", "value" );
HttpServletResponse.addCookie(cookie);
```

Comment: Hi Neha, This is not what i need.Using this we can set a cookie for the domain which is making the call. ie for abc.com not xyz.com. I think it is not possible. With javascript it is possible but it doesnt support cross domain calls. Thanks for the reply.